# can not left align with cowplot package

Tags: r, ggplot2, flextable, cowplot

In the current plot, `p2` is now centered. I want `p2` to be aligned with `p1` on the left. I tried some of the parameters in plot_grid, but the image didn't change at all.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(flextable)
library(grid)
library(cowplot)
library(tidyverse)

mydf <- tibble(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,4),
               b = c(4,4,4,3,3,3))

p1 <- mydf %>% ggplot(aes(x = a, y = b, color = as.factor(b))) + geom_point()

ft_raster <- mydf %>% flextable::flextable() %>% 
  as_raster()

p2 <- ggplot() + 
  theme_void() + 
  annotation_custom(rasterGrob(ft_raster), xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf)

# orginal plot
cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow = 2, ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(1, 1) )

# left align plot (Nothing changed with orginal plot)
cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow = 2, ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(1, 1), align = 'v' )
cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow = 2, ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(1, 1), axis = 'l' )
cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow = 2, ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(1, 1), axis = 'tblr' )
```

Comment: zhiwei, is this a problem that only occurs with that rastered flex_table object?

Comment: @ tjebo, yes, I thought that would not happen if `p2` is a normal ggplot object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the raster object is placed bang in the middle of your plot. Check `ggplot() + annotation_custom(rasterGrob(ft_raster))` without `theme_void`. You can play around with the coordinates for your raster (by the way, the `Inf`s are defaults...

```r
library(flextable)
library(grid)
library(cowplot)
library(tidyverse)

mydf <- tibble(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,4),
               b = c(4,4,4,3,3,3))

p1 <- mydf %>% ggplot(aes(x = a, y = b, color = as.factor(b))) + geom_point()

ft_raster <- mydf %>% 
  flextable::flextable() %>% 
  as_raster()

p2 <-
  ggplot() + 
  theme_void() +
# play around with this !
  annotation_custom(rasterGrob(ft_raster), xmax = 0.2)

cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow = 2, ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(1, 1) )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>